# Circle within a drop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, shapes, drop, mathematical-expressions, wolframalpha

How to create a program in mathematica that automatically adjusts a perfect circle inside the drop shape so that the outside parts of the circle are added part by part and returns us a value? As in the attached figure.

[Droplet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryCtL.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TeardropCurve.html

```
Manipulate[Show[{
   ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t] Sin[t/2]^3}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
   ParametricPlot[{x Cos[t] - (1 - x), x Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]}],
 {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]